# flutter: Update values state in separate class with stream instead of setState()?

Tags: flutter, stream, future, setstate, auto-update

Im currently building an app that gets data from a separate class.
When the list devices gets filled, it should add an container to a Scrolable list.
I already managed to do that part, but.. cause the state of the devices list won't update on change the ui won't add an container either. And I can't use set state in the separate class..

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    getDevices();
  }

  Future<void> getDevices() async {
    setState(() async {
      
    deviceLength = drs.devices.length;

      await drs.allDevices(specificDevices: 'DRS');
    });
  }
```

set state only updates deviceLength on start, but won't continue.

The length of devices is defined by following stream in a separate class Bluetooth, that adds objects to the List devices :

```
Future<Stream<void>> _findSingleResult({searchFor: ''}) async {
    _flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) async {
      // Return found Devices
      try {
        print('Device Found ? $deviceFound');
        print(results.last.device.name);
        //Does found device equal searched Device?
        if (results.last.device.name.contains(searchFor)) {
          deviceFound = true;
          devices.add(results.last.device);
          print('Device found...');
          await _flutterBlue.stopScan();
          return;
        }
        _counter++;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

If anyone knows how to solve this Issue pls help :)

Comment: using provider plugin url link : https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Oh ok. But is there also a way to stream a change of a variable that can then be listened to without implementing this plugin?

Comment: The important thing is that the app (screen) should be able to know that the data has changed. There is no other way to do that than setState. Provider also uses setState inside.